# Is it advisable to use Redis in real time production application?

Tags: redis

I am working on a Crawling application where i need extremely fast insertion and selection database. I found Redis and it solve my purpose. My question is " Is it advisable to use Redis in real time production application?". I read some blog and they suggest Redis in not reliable. Please suggest.

Comment: Redis is production ready. Many projects use it.

Comment: As of April 2013, Pinterest mature architecture using 110 Redis instances : http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/4/15/scaling-pinterest-from-0-to-10s-of-billions-of-page-views-a.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Instagram, Github, Stack Overflow, Pinterest, Twitter, Tumblr, Twilio, Fullscreen, Craigslist, YouPorn and EngineYard and much more companies use Redis.

- [Redis Roundup: What Companies Use Redis?](http://blog.togo.io/redisphere/redis-roundup-what-companies-use-redis/)
- [How Twitter use Redis](http://blog.gopivotal.com/case-studies-2/case-study-staple-yourself-to-a-tweet-to-understand-30-billion-redis-updates-per-day)
- [How HipChat scales to 1 Billion Messages](http://blog.hipchat.com/2013/10/16/how-hipchat-scales-to-1-billion-messages/)
- [YouPorn - Targeting 200 Million Views A Day And Beyond](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/2/youporn-targeting-200-million-views-a-day-and-beyond.html)
- [8 Ways Media Giant Viacom Uses Redis to Serve Dynamic Video At Scale](http://blog.gopivotal.com/case-studies-2/8-ways-media-giant-viacom-uses-redis-to-serve-dynamic-video-at-scale)
- [Scaling Pinterest - From 0 To 10s Of Billions Of Page Views A Month In Two Years](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/4/15/scaling-pinterest-from-0-to-10s-of-billions-of-page-views-a.html)